# Function mcrypt_module_close() is deprecated in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, mcrypt, porto-theme

```
Array
(
    [type] => 8192
    [message] => Function mcrypt_module_close() is deprecated
    [file] => /vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/Mcrypt.php
    [line] => 94
)
```

`PHP Version 7.1.27`
This Issue facing after upgrade Magento 2.1 to Magento2.3.1 with Porto theme version 3.7.1

Anysolution for that?

Comment: Do u got the solution?  i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the PHP version from `7.1.27` to either `7.1.3` or `7.2.0`. You can see more details on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html.

Hope this will fix your issue

Comment: Not working Guy

Comment: Can you please add '@ ' before mcrypt_module_close function?
So replace mcrypt_module_close to @mcrypt_module_close. Let me know if you are still facing the issue

Comment: default added "@" in magento2.3.1 but issue still

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-upgrade. To clarify, you need to upgrade the PHP version up to min 7.2 while yours is 7.1. However, the requirement of Magento 2.3 is that the PHP version needs to be > 7.2

I want to share the link docs for you once again: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html